# Find largest match in list

Tags: python, list, max, min, dictionary

I've been trying to find the largest result in a list - using the confidence value.

Examples of the lists:

```
[[{u'categories': [u'health-beauty'], u'confidence': 0.3333333333333333},
 {u'categories': [u'activities-events'], u'confidence': 0.6666666666666666}]]
```

Would return the **activities-events** dictionary

```
[[{u'categories': [u'home-garden'], u'confidence': 0.3333333333333333},
 {u'categories': [u'None of These'], u'confidence': 0.3333333333333333},
 {u'categories': [u'toys-kids-baby'], u'confidence': 0.3333333333333333}]]
```

Would return **all three** as they are equal

```
[[{u'categories': [u'entertainment'], u'confidence': 1.0}]]
```

Would return **entertainment**

I tried to utilise python's max function:

```
seq = [x['confidence'] for x in d[0]]
max(seq)
```

but that just returns the value

Comment: 'the largest result' using what rule?

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks @Tichodroma will go ahead and do that.

Comment: question and what you want should be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the maximum confidence as in your own example, then use `filter` to create a list of all the maximum records:

```
max_conf = max(x['confidence'] for x in d[0])
filter(lambda x: x['confidence']==max_conf, d[0])
```

As noted in the comment below, `filter` could be replaced with list comprehension:

```
max_records = [x for x in d[0] if x['confidence'] == max_conf]
```

Comment: you might mean: `max_conf = max(x['confidence'] for x in d[0]); result = [x for x in d[0] if x['confidence'] == max_conf]`

Comment: No, I did mean to use the filter function, although I see I got the arguments wrong so I'll correct it.  Of course, list comprehension is another way to it.

Comment: it is still incorrect: `max(d[0], key=lambda x: x['confidence'])` returns the whole dictionary, not just `'confidence'` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
max(d[0], key=lambda x: x['confidence'])
```

returns the whole element from `d[0]` with the highest `confidence` attribute.

Another way:

```
import operator as op

max(d[0], key=op.attrgetter('confidence'))
```

Comment: Was really hoping that it could return all three in the 0.3333 example. But this will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(d[0], key=lambda k: k['confidence'])[-1]
```

Just one more approach. Also returns the whole element from `d[0]` with the highest `confidence` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all the matches with highest confidence, `max` is not the option. You first need to sort it by key  = confidence (you can use [sorted](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) for the purpose, and [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to retrieve the key) and then group the elements (you can use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) based on the confidence. Finally return the group with the highest confidence

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
groups = groupby(sorted(inlist[0], key = itemgetter(u'confidence'), reverse = True),
                 key = itemgetter(u'confidence'))
[e[u'categories'] for e in next(groups)[-1]]
```

Examples

```
>>> inlist = [[{u'categories': [u'health-beauty'], u'confidence': 0.3333333333333333}, {u'categories': [u'activities-events'], u'confidence': 0.6666666666666666}]]
>>> groups = groupby(sorted(inlist[0], key = operator.itemgetter(u'confidence'), reverse = True),key = operator.itemgetter(u'confidence'))
>>> [e[u'categories'] for e in next(groups)[-1]]
[[u'activities-events']]
>>> inlist = [[{u'categories': [u'home-garden'], u'confidence': 0.3333333333333333}, {u'categories': [u'None of These'], u'confidence': 0.3333333333333333}, {u'categories': [u'toys-kids-baby'], u'confidence': 0.3333333333333333}]]
>>> groups = groupby(sorted(inlist[0], key = operator.itemgetter(u'confidence'), reverse = True),key = operator.itemgetter(u'confidence'))
>>> [e[u'categories'] for e in next(groups)[-1]]
[[u'home-garden'], [u'None of These'], [u'toys-kids-baby']]
>>> inlist = [[{u'categories': [u'entertainment'], u'confidence': 1.0}]]
>>> groups = groupby(sorted(inlist[0], key = operator.itemgetter(u'confidence'), reverse = True),key = operator.itemgetter(u'confidence'))
>>> [e[u'categories'] for e in next(groups)[-1]]
[[u'entertainment']]
>>>
```